# Howto installing MySQL binary files

Tags: mysql

I've got a lot of .frm, .myd, .myi that i've downloaded. Google tells me they are MySQL binary files, but how do I go about it to install them on my local MySQL server running on my Windows7 machine? I've got the workbench app, is there a way using it?

in advance, thanks

Comment: Where did you download these from? If at all possible, get a proper dump instead

Comment: Why are you downloading `.frm`, `.myd`, `.my` files? Those are tables (datafiles). You generally put them in your MySQL data directory (see your `my.cnf` to find out where).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the source and the target mySQL version are exactly the same, it *may* be possible to copy these files into your mySQL data directory (see below for the steps). But it's **not a good practice** in any case. It is much preferable to get a proper `mysqldump` dump and import that.

Here's how to copy the files (**this is not recommended**):

- Stop mySQL server
- Locate data directory
- Create folder in data directory (that will be the database)
- Copy files into folder
- Restart mySQL server

Comment: @Jason then you should really get a proper SQL dump if at all possible. You could fiddle with `myisamchk` to fix the tables but that's a horrible kludge, and should be done only as a last resort to extract some data from a backup for example

Comment: It was only some tables I found online, but i think i have to find another source, that has propper dumps. :(